To Do Flask App Edit Function Not Working? (DB Structure)
I am making a Flask To Do App (as a learning project) and based on the below code I get a 400 error .
To Do List DB definitions
class AllToDoLists(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'all_to_do_lists'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    tasks = db.relationship('TaskList', backref='alltodolist', lazy=True)

class TaskList(db.Model):
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(50), default="open")
    list_name = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('all_to_do_lists.id'))
    

Database Sample
screenshot from database
To Do List Edit Function
@app.route('/tick/edit/<int:n>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def tick_edit(n):
    task = TaskList.query.get(n)
    lists = AllToDoLists.query.all()
    currentlist = AllToDoLists.query.get(task.list_name)
    if request.method == "POST":
        task.description = request.form['task']
        task.list = request.form['list']
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template("tick_edit.html", task=task, lists = lists, currentlist=currentlist )

To Do List Edit HTML Form

            <form action="{{ url_for('tick_edit', n=task.id) }}" method="POST">
                <textarea name="task" rows="5" cols="30">{{task.description}}</textarea></br>
                <select name="list">
                    {%for list_item in lists%}
                    {% if list_item == currentlist%}
                    <option value="{{list_item.name}}" selected> {{list_item.name}}</option>
                    {% else %}
                    <option value="{{list_item.name}}"> {{list_item.name}}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}   </select></br>
                <input type="submit"> 
            </form>
           

I tried if request.method == "POST":  and the page loaded properly but of course did not save the changes to the database (where I learned POST =/= post)
I tried commenting out the list update (I realize I need some work there since List_Name is integer but my form is picking from the actual string of name)  and keeping just the description and its the same issue.
I somehow feel like its something glaringly obvious but I've looked at it, compared to identical "features" in the "app" that work normally, and asked ChatGPT to no success.
The expectation is that the page present the current description of task in an editable field (this works when the page does load), the list (which defaults to the current list) so it can be changed. When I click submit, the update is made to the according fields in the database.

task.list = request.form['list'] -> Your TaskList class doesn't have an attribute named list. Did you mean list_name?
